# How to get ip to information with maxmind javascript

Tags: javascript, php, maxmind

I want to get user's ip, location, city, country etc with maxmind javascript but I got null 
there are any mistake by me?

also I have a question may I place maxmind javascript to my plugin for unlimited use?

**My javascript here:**

```
<script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#country").html(document.write(geoip_country_code()));
    $("#countryname").html(document.write(geoip_country_name()));
    $("#city").html(document.write(geoip_city()));
    $("#region").html(document.write(geoip_region()));
    $("#regionname").html(document.write(geoip_region_name()));
</script>
```

**HTML HERE**

```
<div id="country">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="countryname">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="city">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="region">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="regionname">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `document.write` inside a jQuery command? The following outputs my location correctly. As per the usage limits, you'll have to read [their terms of service](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/javascript/).

```js
$("#country").html( 'Country: ' + geoip_country_code() );
$("#countryname").html( 'Country name: ' + geoip_country_name() );
$("#city").html( 'City: ' + geoip_city() );
$("#region").html( 'Region: ' + geoip_region() );
$("#regionname").html( 'Region name: ' + geoip_region_name() );
```

```css
div:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: #e0e0e0;
}
div:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: #a5a5a5;
}
div {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="country"></div>
<div id="countryname"></div>
<div id="city"></div>
<div id="region"></div>
<div id="regionname"></div>
```

Comment: working thanx :)
but if i use maxmind's js to my site with 50000 impression per day .... it is free ?? for user ?

Comment: I don't know, their page says you have to pay.

Comment: oh, I just really saw, 50k per day!, I doubt you'll get a free ride ;)

Comment: yes dont know how this js works but if i use it in my high traffic website :( dont know about charge